# $scope.myFunction is not defined

Tags: angularjs

[image]I am having following angularjs code :

This code displays alert-"inside controller" but after that it is not displaying next alerts and stops with the following error in console

> $scope.getResultsPage is not defined.

```
app.controller('CategoryController',function(dataFactory,$scope,$http){
             var API_URL = 'http://localhost:90/laravel_new/public';
             $scope.categories = [];
             alert("inside controller");

             $scope.getResultsPage(1);

             $scope.getResultsPage = function(pageNumber){
             alert("inside method");       

             dataFactory.httpRequest(API_URL +'/listCategory?page='+pageNumber).then(function(data) {
                 alert("fetchedd...");
             });

         }

       });
```

Anyone please help in this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: call the $scope.getResultspage(1); after your $scope.getResultspage ends not before the function start.

Comment: You have some problems with the brackets also..

Comment: comment or remove  dataFactory.httpRequest code and check if  alert("inside method");  call or not because function you write its ok may be problem in  your  dataFactory

Comment: where is this API_URL declare?

Comment: You should define the function first then call it after.

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.controller('CategoryController',function(dataFactory,$scope,$http){
     $scope.categories = [];
     alert("inside controller");



     $scope.getResultsPage = function(pageNumber){
      alert("inside method"); 
     }     

       $scope.getResultsPage(1); 

     dataFactory.httpRequest(API_URL +'/listCategory?page='+pageNumber).then(function(data) {
         alert("fetchedd...");
     });

 });
```

Call function ,after defining it.And be careful about curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('CategoryController',function(dataFactory,$scope,$http){
             var API_URL = 'http://localhost:90/laravel_new/public';
             $scope.categories = [];
             alert("inside controller");



             $scope.getResultsPage = function(pageNumber){
                  alert("inside method");  

             }

            $scope.getResultsPage(1);

       });
```

This is worked for me. there was problem in dataFactory. Thanks @pravin

Comment: I think problem in API_URL where this variable declare

Comment: when i put my dataFactory code, then page starts loading infine times